How to elegantly handle optional arguments when all optional arguments are explicitly defined but is called with dict unpack which key may not exist?
My question is about Pythonic way of defining the function elegantly when all optional keyword arguments are defined explicitly, but function call arguments to be unpack dynamically from a dictionary **.
Example: I want my function to be defined as follows (or equivalent):
def say(greeting='Hello', message=None):
    print(greeting)
    print(message)

This is basic use case
amy = {
    'greeting': 'Morning',
    'message': 'World',
}
say(**amy)

How can I elegantly unpack dictionary in which there might be keys in the dictionary that are not optional arguments? i.e.
# Dict may have some other keys
bob = {
    'greeting': 'Salute',
    'message': 'Whoa',
    'year': '2024',
}
# Expected:
# TypeError: say() got an unexpected keyword argument 'year'
say(**bob) 

Solutions

Just filter the dictionary before passing it to the function:
 say(**{k: bob[k] for k in {'greeting','message'}}

What bothers me is the filter task. First it assume that key exist, which may not always. I could simply use bob.get(k), but this will overwrite the default value that I have explicitly defined in the function definition. Solution #2 below solve this issue.

Accept **kwargs in the function definition, but don't use it:
def say(greeting='Hello', message=None, **kwargs):
    print(greeting)
    print(message)
say(**bob)

What bothers me is that unused variable still have to be defined. So, Solution #3.

Use _ underscore as a throwaway variable
def say(greeting='Hello', message=None, **_):
    print(greeting)
    print(message)
say(**bob)

Well, I can't complain to this. At least some will know that underscore is a throwaway variable and is a way out. But is this the Pythonic solution for such definition?



according to this post option 3 seems the most correct

@Kenzo "Most correct" is debatable. Should the function signature adapt to the caller, or should the caller adapt to the function…?

@deceze uh... fair question. option one looked like a mess so i automatically disregarded it i guess. Ignore my previous comment.

Let's close this question as I have just went to the duplicated link. I'm looking for a more Pythonic solution. But From the dup link, there seems to be no pythonic way as of now, but #2 seems to be more commonly accepted. Maybe I'll add #3 there as an alternative.
